# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript On Page_Load Not Working on Framework 2.0

Tags: javascript, .net-2.0, scriptmanager, pageload, registerstartupscript

It's a very strange problem

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1,UpdatePanel1.GetType(),"Script","Test()",true);
}
```

my code is not working but on button click event it works
I know it's from the 2.0 version because on 4.0 it works but i really need it on 2.0 framework and on page load.
So if there is an alternative method or solution i will be very thankful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem?

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript is executed on page_load but without any effect,this problem is occuring on framework 2.0, but on framework 4.0 there isn't a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a random value :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(UpdatePanel1) , new Guid().ToString(),"Test();",true);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it this was the issue :] i was spending a whole day on it . Thank you very much

Comment: `new Guid()` makes an "empty" all-0 guid (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 is not very useful).

`Guid.NewGuid()` makes an actual guid with a unique value, what you probably want.